# find the current cursor word and find the all the same word from before the cursor line the cursor line in vim

Tags: unix, vim

find the word which is in the cursor position before the current line
lets assume that if my cursor is in line the cursor on the word is "and" 
i want to move the cursor to all "and" before the cursor line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `#`. If you want to search forward, use `*`.

[Here](http://www.viemu.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.gif) is a memo of basic vim features.